# Simulator keeps defaulting to old Main form

Tags: codenameone

I change the Main Form setting in my codenameone project properties but when I run the simulator it keeps coming up with the earlier setting. My codenameone is updated to latest. What could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the resource file and save it to regenerate the state machine base class over again. This is a known bug in the plugin.

Comment: Open the designer tool, select the new main form. Go to the "misc" tab and press set as main form. Save again. That must work.